# Elastic Search Bulk Push Data Missing on huge data push on batch

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, elasticsearch

Having a problem in count mis match and doc missing while pushing data to elastic search in bulk.

Say a scenario like i have 2 52000 records in an sql data base which is retrieved using a query or formated query function by batch by batch like offset and limit as follows

Batch 1 - 1 to 300 records (Offset : 0 , Limit : 300 )
Batch 2 - 301 to 600 records (Offset : 300, Limit: 300)
......

this is running in a loop at my javascript application.

inside the loop i am pushing data to insert using elastic search Bulk API.

```
const data = { 
{index :{ _index: bills _id: 1212},
{{billId: 1212, billName: "books", createdOn: "23-2-2022"}},
{index :{ _index: bills _id: 1213},
{{billId: 1213, billName: "ink", createdOn: "24-2-2022"}},
....
}
```

`const response = await this.elasticsearchService.bulk(data);`

my response is not showing any error on the missing document.

finally the count is not matching to 52000. some of the documents are missing.

how to find the missing docs and resolve it to push again.

my loop function

```
for (let startCount = offset; startCount <= totalCount; startCount += limitCount) {
            if (startCount + limitCount > totalCount) {
                shouldStopLoop = true;
                limitCount = totalCount - startCount;
            }
 if (limitCount === 0) {
                Logger.log(COMMON_CONSTANT.NO_ES_PAYLOAD, limitCount.toString());
                this.taskHelpers.onJobCompletes(jobType, totalCount);
                return;
            }
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
            await this.fetchAndPushData(startCount, limitCount, this.pushOptions); //---> this method will have the bulk api
}
```

```
    public fetchAndPushData = async (offset: number, limit: number, pushOptions: ESPUSHOPTIONS) => {
            Logger.log(offset, LOGGER_CONSTANT.INFO.OFFSET_INFO);
            Logger.log(limit, LOGGER_CONSTANT.INFO.LIMIT_INFO);
            try {
                const tableRecordDetails = await this.getRecordDetails(TASK_CONST.RECORD_TYPE.DATA, limit, offset);
                // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-object-injection
                if (!tableRecordDetails || tableRecordDetails.length === 0 || !tableRecordDetails[0][dataKey]) {
                    Logger.error(TASK_CONST.RECORD_TYPE.DATA, COMMON_CONSTANT.NO_DATA);
                }
                // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-object-injection
                const data = tableRecordDetails[0][dataKey];
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-magic-numbers
                const esPayload = await this.taskHelpers.formatESPayload(data);
                const response = await this.taskHelpers.pushDataToES(esPayload);
    Logger.log(resonse.body.error, "Is Error")
    }
    catch(error)
    {
    throw error
    }
    }
```

Comment: fwiw, your SQL should be keeping `limit` the same (300) and only change `offset`. limit is the number of records to return. your batch example shows limit being increased every query. i'm not sure there's enough info here to see your issue, though. perhaps show your loop that pushes data to elastic-search. showing more code is a good thing on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes limit is 300 fixed